# Word for a gift you get by virtue of your job

Tags: adjectives, business-language, obscure-terms, government

I am certain I once read a definition of a word that describes the gift you get only by virtue of your job and not really given to you personally. Like, when the US President gets a rug from the Ambassador from Afghanistan, it's not for Barack Obama the person, it would have been given to whomever the US President was at the time. I have searched and searched, and although I have found amusing examples of gifts and the laws, rules and etiquette around them, I haven't found this word. Can anyone help?

Comment: Complimentary gift? :)

Comment: I presume you have discarded the expressions: [Gifts of State](http://www.jimmycarterlibrary.gov/documents/stgifts.phtml), Head of State Gifts and [Foreign Official Gifts](http://www.reagan.utexas.edu/archives/reference/gifts.html). I

Comment: I guess "swag" just doesn't really cut it for Presidential things.

Comment: All the answers (even "swag" :) ) are accurate but not what I was looking for. It's a single word, and it has the vibe of inurement or consideration, but is more specific and way more obscure. Inurement is close, though. I wonder if that's what I read and I just misremember...

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the term for this, at least according to the U.S. government, is "**protocol gift**".  From the homepage of the U.S. Department of State's "Protocol Gift Unit":

> The Protocol Gift Unit within the Office of the Chief of Protocol
>   serves as the central processing point for all tangible gifts received
>   from foreign sources by employees of the Executive Branch of the
>   Federal government. The Unit is responsible for the creation and
>   maintenance of the official record of all gifts presented by the
>   Department of State to officials of foreign governments.

Comment: I voted for Protocol gift. Variants are "diplomatic gift" or "diplomatic present".

Comment: It's a single word, though.